# Floating ImageView on ActionBar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am fairly new to android development and trying to learn as much as i can by doing problems, recently i have come up with a problem related to xml designing where there is a

> floating Imageview on top of the Actionbar

. I am calling it floating because it is not in the action bar, it is just positioned center and overlapping the action bar. The Image would describe it properly - [image]

The Action bar is not collapsing and the round image is not a button just a simple imageview. Now how can i achieve this design?? any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `CoordinatorLayout` allows you to use an `anchor` property on views which will make implementing this really simple.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html):

> Children of a CoordinatorLayout may have an anchor. This view id must
>   correspond to an arbitrary descendant of the CoordinatorLayout, but it
>   may not be the anchored child itself or a descendant of the anchored
>   child. This can be used to place floating views relative to other
>   arbitrary content panes.

Which means, all you'll need to do is use a `CoordinatorLayout` as the top-level container, wrap the toolbar in an `AppBarLayout`, and anchor the image view to that.